# Using a custom summary function for factors within multiple columns

Tags: r, forcats

I conducted a survey with a large number of items, each of which has distinct categorical response options stored as factors. I need to summarize these columns in an efficient manner, preferably with functionality like that provided by `forcats::fct_count()`. I also need to know how many non-NA responses were provided for each variable, since different items were shown to different respondents. I wrote a function to make a tidy little summary data frame, but **am struggling to efficiently run this function along each column and then combine the results into a single object (ala `ddply`)**.

I've tried `sapply()`, `gather()`-ing the data to long format and then running `ddply()`, but the problem of the distinct levels for each variable seems to keep getting in the way. See below for a reproducible example of the data set and my summarizing function. I could run the function for each variable (as shown below), but I know there's gotta be a more efficient way to do this that doesn't involve creating a ton of individual summary data-frame objects. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:50),
  X = as.factor(sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 50, replace = TRUE)),
  Y = as.factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", NA), 50, replace = TRUE)),
  Z = as.factor(sample(c("d", "e", "f", "g", "h", NA), 50, replace = TRUE))
)

library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

factorsummaries.f <- function(x) {
  x <- na.omit(x)
  counts <- fct_count(fct_drop(x), sort = T)
  counts$f <- as.character(counts$f)
  total <- data.frame(f = "sum", n = as.numeric(sum(counts$n)))
  return(bind_rows(counts, total))
}

factorsummaries.f(data$X)
factorsummaries.f(data$Y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `purrr::map_dfr`

```
map_dfr(data[,2:ncol(data)], factorsummaries.f, .id = "colname")
#output  


 colname     f     n
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1     X    no    18
 2     X   yes    17
 3     X   sum    35
 4     Y     a    14
 5     Y     c    13
 6     Y     b    12
 7     Y   sum    39
 8     Z     g    10
 9     Z     d     9
10     Z     h     8
11     Z     f     6
12     Z     e     5
13     Z   sum    38
```